# Why do I need to refresh my page even it is built in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, database, express

I've created a Todo application in which on inputting a note it should update the list below. The main home page is not fetching updated todo from database until I refresh the page.

Here's my code for InputTodo.js:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
const InputTodo = () => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { description };
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });

      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Input Todo</h1>

      <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={description}
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default InputTodo;
```

The ListTodo.js is:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import EditTodo from "./EditTodo";

const ListTodos = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  //Delete function
  const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
    try {
      const deleteTodo = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/todos/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
      });

      setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.todo_id !== id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  const getTodos = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos");
      const JsonData = await response.json();
      setTodos(JsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  console.log(todos);
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <table className="table mt-5 text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <tr key={todo.todo_id}>
              <td>{todo.description}</td>
              <td>
                <EditTodo todo={todo} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.todo_id)}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ListTodos;
```

API for Get All Todos:

```
//Get all todos

app.get("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allTodos = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM todo");
    res.json(allTodos.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

It should update the list without refreshing the home page.

Comment: Because there's nothing else there to either update or re-fetch the todos array in the parent component otherwise. For example you could have an extra prop `onEdit={getTodos}`. Being built in React doesn't make it magic.

Answer (score -1):

```
 const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
```

Using preventDefault() stops the form submission from triggering a page reload as it would ordinarily do as an HTML Form element. Of course this is what we want when using React, because React is a SPA (Single Page Application) - we don't want to reload the entire application when submitting a form.

However, within your code you only have one place where data is requested from the server, in ListTodo.js. What should your application do upon submission? Typically you might navigate the user back to a homepage after a form submission for example, but assuming your todo app is a simple app on a single route (page) then perhaps you should think about what happens *after* the POST request.

In the try-catch below you are storing the response but not utilizing it. Was the POST successful on the API? The try-catch won't know anything of this, even a failure, because it only watches for network failures and is not concerned with the API itself. That is your concern, so you should make use of the response; the API should provide a status code for a success or failure - you could also use the API success response to send data back to your react application perhaps.

```
try {
      const body = { description };
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });

      if (!response.ok) throw new Error('POST of Todo unsuccessful') // You should send back a 201 response code for a successful POST that creates a data entry

      // POST was successful at this point; update your Todo state?

      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
};
```